# xlib programming - how to find if the line is outside a given polygon

Tags: c, computational-geometry, xlib, x11

I have a polygon . [image]

How can i find out through xlib programming whether the black color line lies outside the polygon or inside the polygon .

Comment: Hmmm .. this seems an edge case. If start and/or endpoints are *on* the polygon boundary, is that "inside"? What if one point is inside and the other is not? If both points are 'not' inside, you can check if it crosses any of the polygon's edges (and if if enters, then leaves, the polygon -- is *that* "inside"?)

Answer (score 0):

1. **create function that determines if point is inside/on edge/outside polygon**

   if you cast ray (half axis) in any direction from that point to infinity it should intersect odd count of polygon lines if it is inside polygon and even count if it is outside polygon.

   If ray intersection lies directly on some edge (intersection == point) then change a little the direction and try again or handle double hit (from both neighbouring lines of that vertex) as single hit if your polygon is not complex one...
2. **if line does not intersect any polygon line then**

   - if its booth points are inside polygon then line is inside polygon
   - if its booth points are outside polygon then line is outside polygon
   - if one point is inside and one outside then line is partially in
   - if one or the two points are on edge then test the line midpoint instead
3. **if line does intersect any polygon line then**

   and that intersection is not also vertex of the line (on edge) then the line is partially in else is fully in or out according to the second point of the line